# Make .hgignore in a Mercurial repository available to all subrepos?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore, subrepos, hgrc

I have a Mercurial repository with several subrepos. Is there a possibility to only define a general .hgignore-File (e.g. to ignore object-files) both in the main repository and, optionally a specialized one in the sub-repositories?

There is not enough information in the manual. Specifying a .hgignore file with

```
[ui]
ignore = .hgignore
```

to .hgrc in my home-directory also does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A `.hgignore` file in each subrepo would serve as the specialized one for that subrepo. Then you can use the main repo's `.hgignore` as the main one by including this in each subrepo's `hgrc` file:

```
[ui]
ignore.main = \absolute\path\to\mainrepo\.hgignore
```

The reason why doing `ignore = .hgignore` didn't work for you in your global `.hgrc` (and won't in repo `hgrc`) is that having simply `.hgignore` is a relative file path and its resolution to an absolute path depends on the current working directory used when invoking `hg`. Examples:

- If you're in `\repos\main\` and invoke `hg st`, it will look for `\repos\main\.hgignore`. Same thing if you invoke `hg st -R nested`, because the current working directory is still the same.
- But if you were in `\repos\main\nested\` and then invoked `hg st`, the config would now be looking at `\repos\main\nested\.hgignore`.

If you want to specify a global `.hgignore` that is in your home directory, you would need to specify it with a non-relative path (or at least much less relative):

```
[ui]
ignore = ~\.hgignore
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your first bullet-point there. If you invoke `hg st -R nested` then `\repos\main\nested\.hgignore` will be used, as that's the `.hgignore` file in the working directory of the `nested` repo - that may be what you meant, but it doesn't read that way.

Comment: @icabod: I don't have a *nix machine to test with, but that's how Windows behaved. If I have different `extra.hgignore` files in `main` and `nested` and put `ignore = extra.hgignore` in `nested\.hg\hgrc`, doing `hg st` and `hg st -R nested` both pull from `main\extra.hgignore`. Only if I `cd` to `nested` will it instead grab `nested\extra.hgignore`. (For my test I used 4 files in both `main` and `nested`, with 4 different extensions distributed among the ignore files.)

Comment: Ah, I think I missed out a part of your answer when I was trying it out. My mistake :)